# Is it possible to pass records into a collection, and then display them, in a lightning web component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce, lwc

I'm in the midst of creating a lightning web component to visualise salesforce records in the concept of a timeline. I've managed to create my timeline component, styling etc, and retrieve the data using salesforce's fairly recently released API. I've provided a link below, for further information. *I'm fairly new to JavaScript so forgive me if there is any poor mistakes.*

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_get_related_list_records

The problem comes from when I retrieve the data, and attempt to split the records, into different collections based on a fields certain value, it yields no result. I use **for:each** in my HTML to call my collections and no records are displayed.

I believe the problem lies in the for loop that appends the data to the collections, but I'm not sure. I've changed `data[x]` to `this.records[x]` and it yields the same results. I'd appreciate any pointers, and welcome any constructive criticisms.

*Note that when I use the records collection provided by the api the records are displayed.*

**Timeline.js**

```
import { LightningElement,api, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
export default class timeline extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track CompletedTasks = [];
    @track InProgressTasks = [];
    @track OverdueTasks = [];
    error; 
    records;

    @wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '$recordId',
        relatedListId: 'Tasks__r',
        fields: ['Task__c.Id','Task__c.Name', 'Task__c.Estimated_Completion_Date__c', 'Task__c.Completion_Status__c'],
        sortBy: ['Task__c.Estimated_Completion_Date__c'],
        
    })listInfo({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.records = data.records;
            this.error = undefined;
            for (let x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
              if (data[x].Completion_Status__c === "Completed") {
                  this.CompletedTasks.append(data[x]);
              } else if (data[x].Completion_Status__c === "In Progress") {
                  this.InProgressTasks.append(data[x]);
              } else if (data[x].Completion_Status__c === "Overdue") {
                  this.OverdueTasks.append(data[x]);
              }
          }
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.records = undefined;
        }

    }
```

**Timeline.html**

```
<lightning-tab label="All Tasks" value="All Tasks" title = "All Tasks">
   <div style="overflow-x: scroll; height:130px;">
      <div class="tasks-container">
         <template for:each={CompletedTasks} for:item="rec">
            <div key={rec.fields.Id.value}>
               <template if:true={CompletedTasks}>
                  <div class="task-card">
                     <ul class="slds-has-dividers_around-space" draggable="true">
                        <li class="slds-item">
                           <article class="slds-tile slds-tile_board">
                              <h3 class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate" title="Journey Name">
                                 <p style = "font-weight: 600;">Web Development Onboarding</p>
                              </h3>
                              <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                                 <div class="slds-text-heading_small">
                                    <a>
                                    {rec.fields.Name.value}
                                    </a>
                                 </div>
                                 <p class="slds-truncate" title="Esimated Completion Date:">Esimated Completion Date:</p>
                                 <div class = "statusdate">
                                    <p class="slds-truncate" title="Date" style = "width: 200px;">{rec.fields.Estimated_Completion_Date__c.value}</p>
                                    <div class = "statusbuttoncomplete">
                                       <span class="slds-badge slds-theme_success">{rec.fields.Completion_Status__c.value }</span>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </article>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </template>
            </div>
         </template>
      </div>
   </div>
</lightning-tab>
```

Comment: Can you add `this.CompletedTasks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.CompletedTasks));` at the end of your `if(data)` branch?

Comment: @eyescream added, and unfortunately achieves the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You had few syntax errors in the loop.

- There's no `data.length` because data is an object, not an array. You want `data.records.length`.
- And access to field values has to be like what you have in html part (`rec.fields.Completion_Status__c.value`), if you just go `data[x].Completion_Status__c === "Completed"` you're comparing string and complex object again. Yes, it is different to when you use data sent from Apex and slightly annoying but that's standard LWC / UI record API for you...
- It's array.`push()`, not `append()`.
- And html - either you didn't paste everything or there's something fishy around lightning-tab, nothing was rendering.

Try with this (it's converted to display Account Cases, not everybody will have your custom Task__c)

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <template for:each={CompletedTasks} for:item="rec">
            <div key={rec.fields.Id.value}>
                <div class="task-card">
                    <ul class="slds-has-dividers_around-space" draggable="true">
                        <li class="slds-item">
                        <article class="slds-tile slds-tile_board">
                            <h3 class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate" title="Journey Name">
                                <p style="font-weight: 600;">Web Development Onboarding</p>
                            </h3>
                            <div class="slds-tile__detail">
                                <div class="slds-text-heading_small">
                                    <a>
                                    {rec.fields.Subject.value}
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <p class="slds-truncate" title="Esimated Completion Date:">Esimated Completion Date:</p>
                                <div class = "statusdate">
                                    <p class="slds-truncate" title="Date" style = "width: 200px;">{rec.fields.CreatedDate.value}</p>
                                    <div class = "statusbuttoncomplete">
                                    <span class="slds-badge slds-theme_success">{rec.fields.Status.value }</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement,api, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';

export default class Stack74031191 extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track CompletedTasks = [];
    @track InProgressTasks = [];
    @track OverdueTasks = [];
    error; 
    records;

    @wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '$recordId',
        relatedListId: 'Cases',
        fields: ['Case.Id','Case.Subject', 'Case.CreatedDate', 'Case.Status'],
        sortBy: ['Case.CreatedDate'],
        
    })listInfo({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.records = data.records;
            this.error = undefined;

            for (let i = 0; i < data.records.length; ++i) {
                let r = data.records[i];
                let status = r.fields.Status.value;
                if (status === "Closed") {
                    this.CompletedTasks.push(r);
                } else if (status === "New") {
                    this.InProgressTasks.push(r);
                }
            }
            // this.CompletedTasks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.CompletedTasks));
            // this.InProgressTasks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.InProgressTasks));
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.records = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Account</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```